# Approximate matrix inverse by Fourier approach

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, approximation, quantum-computation

Given a hermititan matrix $A$ with  the possibility to generate $e^{-iAt}$ for $t\geq 0$ how would I proceed to approxiamte:

$A^{-1}\approx\sum_j\alpha_je^{-iAt_j}$ $\quad$ with $\alpha_j\in\mathbb{C}$

How could I determine $\alpha_j$ and $t_j$

Comment: Do you have a good reason for thinking this is possible???

Comment: In an algorithm for solving linear equations described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02306.pdf) they use this approximation and call it the Fourier approch. (page 5 line 25)

Comment: Write $A = U\Lambda U^H, \quad A^{-1} = U\Lambda^{-1} U^H$ and use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Diagonalizable_case) property. The problem reduces to approximation of $f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}$ with a linear combination of $e^{-i t_j \lambda}$. The method is described at the bottom of the page 10.

Comment: @uranix Ah. It seems we should only need that approximation for $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, which is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$. Away from the origin if $A$ is invertible, got it.

Comment: You usually don't have $\sigma(A)$ in advance. Especially if your goal is to solve a linear system with matrix $A$. At best you know the interval $[a, b]$ such that $\sigma(A) \subset [a, b]$. So you need to approximate $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ only for $\lambda \in [a, b]$.

Comment: @uranix I can't see how the problem reduces to the approximation of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, shouldn't the approximation also be a matrix? What is the function $f$ you introduced?